# react-native-snap-carousel produces "TypeError: Cannot read property 'array' of undefined, js engine: hermes"

Tags: react-native, react-native-snap-carousel

I'm trying to utilize a very popular react-native library in my expo project. However, when I try to use the the carousel component like this:

```
const renderItem = (item: any) => {
    // Ignore fn args for debugging purposes
    return (
        <Text>Hello World</Text>
    );
};

return (
  <Carousel
    layout={"default"}
    data={[]}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    sliderWidth={400}
    itemWidth={350}
  />
);
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'array' of undefined, js engine: hermes
```

If I remove the <Carousel ... /> component then my react-native project works as expected. Any ideas on what's causing this issue?

According to the error shown on my iOS emulator it seems like the Carousel component is referencing `PropTypes.array` which would explain where the error is coming from.

```
items: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
```

However, being that this library is so popular I'm not sure if it makes sense for this issue to be occurring unless I have some outdated packages or incompatible ones.

[image: iOS Emulator displaying error]

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.10",
    "@react-native-segmented-control/segmented-control": "^2.4.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.38.5",
    "@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.10",
    "base64-arraybuffer": "^1.0.2",
    "expo": "^49.0.21",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.8.3",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.12",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-location": "~16.1.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "nativewind": "2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-heroicons": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.8.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^14.1.0",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "zustand": "^4.4.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.11",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.202",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.45",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.9",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Your installed version of `react-native-snap-carousel` is too old. Please update to latest version ([v3.9.1](https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-snap-carousel)).

Comment: @kiuQ That's strange.. The version in my package.json is what I get from running npm install according to their documentation.

After manually upgrading the version it seems to work, however, when there's an empty list passed to `data` it crashes with this error:

```
[365,"RCTScrollView",{"width":<<NaN>>"}] is not usable as a native method argument
```

Comment: I guess some of the source code didn't handle for empty data case. And when I read those issues in [github](https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-snap-carousel/issues/959), some of the user said that this library is not updated since 2020, so call **deprecated**. They would suggest user to use [react-native-reanimated-carousel](https://reanimated-carousel.dev/),